# Which method is best?

Tags: normal-distribution, anova, variance, spss, kurtosis

I have an independent variable which is BMI and catagorized into
1- under weight
2- normal weight
3- over weight
4- obese

Sample size is 100

The dependent variable for group 1,2 and 3 is not normally distributed, I checked for each group separately using kurtosis and skewness. But for group 4 which I only have 3 cases the kurtosis value is not being calculated.

But I read in some sites that even if your data are not normally distributed you can use anova, but is the kurtosis value not displaying an issue?

And since I have unequal sample size I used welch anova.
Are all these steps correct?

Sample size
Group 1 (71)
Group 2 (15)
Group 3 (11)
Group 4 (3)

Thank you

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the target of your analysis

Comment: @Inuraghe I want to compare means using anova

Comment: Can I ask whether there is a particular reason on binning the BMIs for your analysis? Would that be because e.g. you expect your dependent variable of interest having significant difference between a BMI of 24.9 and a BMI of 25.1 or some other reasons?

Comment: @B.Liu I want to compare the dependent variable across the four groups, I mean to compare means

Comment: Nothing is ever perfectly normally distributed. Using methods assuming normality such as ANOVA will often but not always work well with non-normal data. Problems may occur in case of gross outliers, strong skewness, strongly different variances or distributional shapes between groups, dependence. If you have none of this you should be fine. (It's all better to diagnose from data visualisation than from testing or computing skewness & kurtosis values.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig thank you very much for your answer, if I use simple linear regression is that going to fix the problem?

Comment: Without data visualisation neither am I sure whether you have a problem, nor whether linear regression can fix it.